# How to properly connect python mysql query using if-else and try-except for a delete function in task management system

Tags: python, mysql, if-statement, try-except

I am currently working on a project task management system, and one of the functions is delete a category. I have tried this:

```
def deleteCategory():
    try:
        delcat='DELETE FROM Category WHERE cname = %s'
        catname=str(input("Enter category name: "))
        
    except HandleableErrors:
        print("No categories yet!")
        delcat = False

    finally:
        if delcat:
            values=(catname,)
            mycursor.execute(delcat, values)
            db.commit();
            print("Category deleted.")

        else:
            print("No category like that.")
```

but it still prints "Enter category name: " and "Category deleted" even when there are no categories. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should change `if delcat` in `finally` block to `if catname`. This will not print "Category Deleted".

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def deleteCategory():
try:
    delcat = 'DELETE FROM Category WHERE cname = %s'
    catname = str(input("Enter category name: "))

    values = (catname,)
    mycursor.execute(delcat, values)
    db.commit()
    print("Category deleted.")

except HandleableErrors:
    print("No categories yet!")
    delcat = False

except Exception as e:  // change the Exception to the actual exception type you get when the operation is failing
    print("No category like that.")
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: Change the `Exception` to the actual exception type you get when the operation is failing.